# PHP: write string - from jumbled field get ordered field

Tags: php, class, sorting, field

I am new in PHP and I am working on a exercise, to try understand working with fields:

> You have class "CPerson" with variable "age".
>   Define field of objects in class CPerson.
>   Write string where input will be not organized field and output will be organized field.

Thanks a lot for every answer.

Comment: This makes no sense. Please look through your question and write it in such a way that it makes sense.

Comment: I am not native english speaking. Is it better after edit or still it makes no sense?

Comment: That isn't PHP language

Comment: It is description of what I may write in PHP

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented PHP, class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields".  I hope that helps clarify the concept of "fields".